# Using "not make" in a sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis

The following seems wrong and confusing to me:

> Gifting is not available for split orders. Because you already have items in your cart from Zanybobs shop, adding items from different stores will not make gifting possible

Is there a reason why "adding items from different stores will not make gifting possible" seems confusing, or is it just confusing to me.

Is there a better way to say this?

Comment: Is there any reason to use *gift* as a verb? (This is a rhetorical question; the answer is NO.) While it is popular in certain circles, it makes the statement rather precious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that it doesn't sound correct. The 'not' modifier is in an awkward place and should be attached to the word it is changing (possible).

> ...adding items from different stores will not make gifting possible

should be

> ...adding items from different stores will make gifting not possible

Answer (score 2):

This sentence not is correct, because it means that gifting is not possible and will still not be possible after adding items. You will want to move "not" (with "not possible" becoming "impossible") :

> Because [...] shop, adding items from different stores will make gifting impossible.

Or you could reformulate :

> Because [...] shop, adding items from different stores will disable gifting.

Comment: @Ben Would you check my edits and point out anything still unclear ?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. That is quite an awkward sentence, as it could be interpreted as adding items does not necessarily make gifting possible. It could also be interpreted as adding items makes gifting unavailable.